# Facebook login via Android SDK: Is it possible to get the "code" token without exchanging it for an access token?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to integrate the Facebook SDK into a client-server Android application and can't find a way to delegate the `code`->`access token` exchange step to the server-side. The app uses a non-encrypted connection, so acquiring the access token on the client and sending it to the server is not desirable.

Other OAuth providers (e.g. Google) have a way to configure the SDK to not perform the exchange and only return a temporary token (`code` in Facebook's terms).
Facebook docs mention the "code flow" without giving any particular details.

Is it possible? If so, then how can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking through the SDK docs, reference and code yielded no results. Requesting only the `code` token does not seem to be possible